# Filling the foreign key field in one form from another form of related models in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I got two related tables(models) [**Sub** with primary key `id`] and [**Case** with foreign key `sub_id`]. I created Sub with `id=4`. I want to create data of **Case model** in view.php(form) of **Sub model**. I did a "Create Case" Button which refer to the `actionCreate` of Case model.

This is my "Create Case" button in sub/view.php:

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app','Create Case'), ['/case/create', 'sub_id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

It looks like in the 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjKPd.png)

This button referred me to the create form of Case model, where i should get the field sub_id = 4. Now my _form.php has

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'sub_id')->textInput() ?>
```

What should i change to get the automatically filled field sub_id with id of parent model?

**UPDATE:** I added relevant code from the appropriate view, controller files.
I didn't changed model files.

CaseController.php file looks like shown below

```
class CaseController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new CaseSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
    public function actionCreate($sub_id)
    {
        $model = new Case();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                'parent' => $sub_id
            ]);
        }
    }
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Case::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

sub/view.php file:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

$this->title = $model->id . ": " . $model->fullname;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Subs'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="sub-view">

<h3><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h3>

<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'address_id',
        'address.region.name',
        [
            'label' => 'address',
            'value' => 'Street: ' . $model->address->street . ' House ' . $model->address->house . ' Flat ' . $model->address->flat
        ],
    ],
]) ?>

<p>
    <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Case'), ['/case/create', 'sub_id'=>$model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</p>

</div>
```

case/_form.php file:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

<div class="case-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->textInput() ?>

<?php if($model->isNewRecord && isset($parent_id)) {
    $model->sub_id = $parent_id;
} ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'sub_id')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $model->sub_id]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'case_date')->textInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more information if you want help.

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

With lack of any further information, to the best of my understanding this is what you are asking -

Taking the example in your picture, if user clicks on Create Case button, then a new form (Create Case) will open. In that Create Case form, among other input fields, there is a field for sub_id and it should be populated by default with the value 4 (since in the picture the ID of the User Harry Potter is 4).

Based on the above you simply need to do the following - 
In your action (within the `CaseController`) for create case, you pass the `sub_id` like below -

```
/* ** CaseController ** */
public function actionCreate($sub_id) 
{
    //....other code

    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model,'parent_id' => $sub_id]);
}
```

And then inside the `_form.php` where you are showing the Create Case form you simply do like this -

```
/* ** _form.php ** */
//... other code

//if you are using _form.php for Edit Form as well, 
//this prevents the value from the DB being over-written
if($model->isNewRecord && isset($parent_id)) {
    $model->sub_id = $parent_id;
}
<?= $form->field($model, 'sub_id')->textInput() ?>

//... other code
```

This should be enough to display the value passed from the parent form.

Comment: @sm979 Thanks for your response. Actually You properly understood my question, but your solution is not worked for me. It refers me to the Create Case form, which has an **empty input field** for sub_id.

Comment: @Miracle633 you need to share relevant code from the appropriate view, controller and model files...without that it is difficult to know what is the issue.

Comment: @sm979 I updated question. Added view and controller files

Comment: @Miracle633 one thing that comes to mind is - are you sure you are passing `parent` parameter from the `create` view file to the `_form` view? Also having used `$model->sub_id = $parent_id;` code, you **don't need** to specify the `value` attribute again like this `<?= $form->field($model, 'sub_id')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $model->sub_id]) ?>`. The last part is just about clean code, that should not be the cause of the issue you are facing.

Comment: @sm979 Oh, Its my bad. Also I corrected files as you said, but nothing happened. I only see the empty field.